# Does $\pi(n+r)+\pi(n-r)$ decrease as $r$ increases?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

Assume Goldbach's conjecture. Then for every large enough positive integer $n$ there exists a non negative integer $r$ such that both $n+r$ and $n-r$ are primes. Such an integer $r$ will be called a primality radius of $n$. Let's denote by $r_{0}(n)$ the smallest primality radius of $n$. Considering $r$ ranging from $r_{0}(n)$ to the largest primality radius of $n$, is it true that the quantity $\pi(n+r)+\pi(n-r)$ decreases as $r$ increases? If so, does there exist a universal constant $C$ such that $\pi(n+r_{0}(n))+\pi(n-r_{0}(n)))\lt C.\pi(2n)$? Can we get an estimation of the value of $C$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only want to vary over $r$ which are primality radii?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question, but if $n=144$, the first three primality radii are $5$, $7$ and $35$ corresponding to $288=139+149=137+151=109+179$, and there are more primes ($157$,$163$,$167$,$173$) between $151$ and $179$ than there are ($113$,$127$,$131$) between $109$ and $137$, so $\pi(n+r)+\pi(n-r)$ increases going from the second to the third primality radius.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard: thank you for the counterexample. Still, it would be rather interesting to know the frequency of such "anomalous" variations of the considered quantity.

Comment: As to your second question: $C=2$ works by Bertrand's postulate. Using the prime number theorem, it seems straightforward that any fixed $C>1$ works for $n>n_0(C)$, while $C=1$ probably fails for infinitely many $n$'s.

Comment: "...it would be rather interesting to know the frequency of such "anomalous" variations of the considered quantity." So maybe you should do some computing, say, for all $n$ up to 1,000,000, and report back to us on what you find?